# use str.format() in django logging

Tags: python, django, string, logging, format

I use django 1.6 and python 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04.And i find django logging is using the python's built-in logging module.As the [dictConfig format(python 3.x version)](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema) said, I can use 3 kind format style in setting logging formatter(the %-formatting, {}-formatting, and the $()-formating) while django uses [dictConfig format(python 2.x version)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema) as document.

So can I use different kind of format style in django logging?

like:

```
{
    'format':"{levelname} - {asctime} - {module} - {process} - {thread} - {message}"
}
```

instead of

```
{
    'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
}
```

in django 1.6?

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this, because you control the formatters that you use. Just specify a suitable `style` value in the dict which defines the formatter parameters, e.g.

```
{
    "format": "{levelname} - {asctime} - {module} - {message}",
    "style": "{",
}
```

**Update:** You need to specify the formatter with this dict, for Python 3.2:

```
{
    '()': logging.Formatter,
    'format': '{levelname} - {asctime} - {module} - {message}',
    'style': '{',
},
```

On Python 3.3 or later, the `'()': logging.Formatter` line shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I changed the formatter settting, but it doesn't work.Only logging the `{levelname} - {asctime} - {module} - {message}` in the log file.the formatter setting work only using the %-style .